# Cannot run vagrant.local after "vagrant up" and "vagrant provision"

Tags: wordpress, vagrant

I have a WordPress VIP multisite theme setup which I need to run using vagrant at my local environment.

I ran `vagrant up` and then `vagrant provision` but that does not give me the url (`vagrant.local`) any more. A few months back when I last worked on this site I got this.

Do I need to make any changes in `/etc/hosts` file?

Output of `vagrant up` command:

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:25: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/subrara/.phpbrew/php in PATH, mode 040777
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' is available! You currently
==> default: have version '2.3.5'. The latest is version '201801.02.0'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /var/www/wp-projects/yrc
    default: /var/log/php => /var/www/wp-projects/yrc/logs/php
==> default: Detected mount owner ID within mount options. (uid: 1000 guestpath: /var/log/php)
==> default: Detected mount group ID within mount options. (gid: 1000 guestpath: /var/log/php)
    default: /var/log/nginx => /var/www/wp-projects/yrc/logs/nginx
==> default: Detected mount owner ID within mount options. (uid: 1000 guestpath: /var/log/nginx)
==> default: Detected mount group ID within mount options. (gid: 1000 guestpath: /var/log/nginx)
    default: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-846018e2aa141a5eb79a64b4015fc5f3 => /var/www/wp-projects/yrc/puppet/manifests
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

Output of `vagrant provision` command:

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:25: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/subrara/.phpbrew/php in PATH, mode 040777
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20180118-22825-89veip.sh
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with development.pp...
==> default: Notice: Compiled catalog for vagrant.local in environment production in 3.86 seconds
==> default: Notice: Finished catalog run in 5.38 seconds
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20180118-22825-uoa51f.sh
```

When I ran `http://vagrant.local`, I got the following message:

> Unable to load wpcom-legacy-redirector-1.3.0 (plugins) using
>   wpcom_vip_load_plugin()!

My Vagrantfile is inside `/var/www/wp-projects/wpms` folder and I am running `vagrant` commands from this directory. However, the path of my theme is `/var/www/wp-projects/wpms/wp/wp-contnet/themes/vip/tourism-theme`

Am I missing something? I am not a regular user of vagrant environment. I am on Ubuntu 140.04.

EDIT:

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Random quick guess - it might be a wordpress plugin issue. Do you have access to your worpress' admin ? If yes, go there and update your plugins, it might solve the issue.

Comment: I am on localhost. Shall I try grabbing the plugin and update manually by putting it in plugins folder in my localhost? I don't have access to update plugins :(

Comment: Yes, you should try that

Comment: But how would I know which plugin to update? One more thing, when I last worked on this site, after running `vagrant provision`, as far as I remember it provided me a link in green color, which I don't get now.

Comment: Just try to use the latest one [link](https://github.com/svn2github/wordpress-vip-plugins/tree/master/wpcom-legacy-redirector-1.3.0) and you can also try to load this under mu-plugins folder

Comment: it's more a problem of wordpress plugin rather than vagrant.

Comment: @RagZ, shall I download this plugin and put it directly inside mu-plugins folder? You said "use the latest", but I don't see any folder named `wpcom-legacy-redirector-1.3.0` inside my current mu-plugin folder.

Comment: yes give it a shot. Make sure you remove the existing plugin thats causing this issue. mu-plugin folder acts as a must use plugin and auto enables.

Comment: Sorry again, how do I know which plugin is causing the issue? I have uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: The redirector plugin, just remove that and add the new one thats mentioned on the link

Comment: Thank you! Since I don't have the folder inside my existing mu-plugin folder (don't know why), I downloaded the plugin and placed it inside it. However, the problem still persists! :(

Comment: For time being just disable all the plugins and see if the site is loading. Especially the redirect plugin

Comment: I cannot load the site at all! When I run vagrant.local/ the message appears and nothing else is on the page.

Comment: Commenting out the line `wpcom_vip_load_plugin( 'wpcom-legacy-redirector', 'plugins', '1.3.0' );` has done the trick and site is finally running. Although its a dirty fix, and I would love to know about the right method to do it, at least I am in now!

Answer (score 0):

I got it sorted out with the help of my senior! Here is what I did.
The plugin is actually a part of WordPress VIP plugin and it resides under `wp-content/themes/vip/plugins` directory. The latest to be pulled into this directory. Once I did that, everything started working just fine!

Comment: Adding a note that this appears to have been for a VIP site on WordPress.com, which is a platform no longer used by WordPress VIP; a more flexible platform (internally called VIP Go) is now used.

The https://github.com/Automattic/WPCOM-Legacy-Redirector/ plugin is still available as a standalone plugin though.